# The way to use Redis in Apache Flink

Tags: redis, apache-flink

I am using the Flink and want to insert the result value into the Redis.
When I googled the Redis, I found the `redis-connector` included in the Apache bahir.
So I am able to insert the result value into the redis using the `reids-connector` in the Apache bahir.

However, I think that I am also able to connect to the Redis using the `Jedis`.
I had the experiment showing that I was able to connect the redis and found the value inserted into the redis using `jedis` as shown in the code below.

```
  DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(flinkParams.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), flinkParams.getProperties())).setParallelism(Math.min(hosts * cores, kafkaPartitions));

        messageStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(String s) throws Exception {
                return s;
            }
        }).flatMap(new RedisConnector());
```

In the `RedisConnector` module, without the `redis-connector` in the Apache bahir, I also successfully connected to the redis and found the message processed after the Flink.
The example code is shown as below

```
public class ProcessorCommon {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessorCommon.class);

    private Jedis jedis;

    private Set<DummyPair> dummy;

    public ProcessorCommon(String redisServerHostName) {
        this.jedis = new Jedis(redisServerHostName);
    }

    public void writeToRedis(String key, String value) {
        this.jedis.set(key, value);
    }

    public String getFromRedis(String key) {
        return this.jedis.get(key);
    }

    public void close() {
        this.jedis.close();
    }
}
```

So I am wondering that there is a difference between using `redis-connector` in the bahir and `Jedis`.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no real Redis connector maintained by the Flink community. The Redis connector in Bahir is rather outdated. There is a new Redis Streams connector in the works, which can be found at https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-redis-streams

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about the case that uses the jedis in code level as shown in a code snippet in the question instead of using the flink-redis-connector?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jedis so I can't answer that for you unfortunately